# how to end a reactor event loop in ace

Tags: ace, reactor

I found two ways of ending a reactor event loop in ace:

```
1. ACE_Reactor::instance()->end_reactor_event_loop();
2. ACE_Reactor::instance()->close()
```

What is the difference between them? Which should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want to do:

Take a look at [this documentation](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/6.0.7/html/libace-doc/a00523.html#a9b149030c2a4efe9529940cd9aaecc8f)

Basically the difference between the 2 is:

`end_reactor_event_loop` stops processing of the messages by the reactor but doesn't free resources and doesn't drop any messages already in the queues.

`close` on the other hand will do above and release all the resources associated with the implementation of the `ACE_Reactor::intance()`, consequently dropping messages deleting all sockets and handlers associated with the reactor, etc.

So depending on what you are doing you can choose one or the other beyond that you would need to provide more details.

Comment: I tried end_reactor_event_loop() in destructor and it took 30sec to shutdown. Close() takes seconds.

Comment: Simple but elaborate answer, It helped me a lot.